# Can "quite" modify adjectives and adverbs in the comparative degree?

Tags: adverbs, comparative-degree

> They laughed, they cried, but it was not *quite better* than ''Cats.'' They were there, after all, to buy Memories. (**The New York Times**)
>
> “Oh my God! Wembley Stadium. Yeah, my God. So it’s going to be *quite bigger*.” It certainly is. The other difference from the time Domingo, Pavarotti and Carreras entertained the multitudes during the Euro 96 football tournament is that this time Domingo won’t be singing a note. (**The Telegraph**)
>
> I want to take this opportunity to thank Steve Waugh, because to all us youngsters - and I am *quite younger* than him - he has been an inspiration. (**BBC Sport**)

My grammar book, written by an Italian teacher, says that "*Quite* is not used directly before comparatives", but I found several occurences of this usage.

Question is, can we use "quite" directly before comparatives?

Answer (score 5):

SHORT VERSION:
Don’t use it.

LONG VERSION:
In your first example *not quite better* is not parsed as **[not][quite better]** but as **[not quite][better]**; that is, *not quite* is a fixed expression meaning ‘almost’, ‘falling just short of’. This is fine.

But this *not quite* does not behave the same way as bare *quite*.  *Quite ADJer* is and not unknown, but it is very rare, comparable to *very ADJer*. Take a look at this [Google Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=quite+better*1000%2Cmuch+better%2Cvery+better*1000&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), where I have multiplied the instances of *quite better* and *very better* by 1000 and they are still outranked by *much better*:

[image: QuiteMuchVeryBetter]

I note that your second and third examples are uttered by a native speaker of Italian and a speaker of Indian English.

There is as far as I know no reason why *very* and *quite* should not be used with comparatives; but they aren’t.

Comment: I think your penultimate paragraph should probably have come first, since presumably that "misparsing" is what prompted OP to ask the question in the first place. It's equally valid to replace *not quite* by, for example, *almost*, or *[very] nearly* - which are perfectly normal words to occur before *ADJer* forms.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I took a peek at some of the _quite better_ hits. One context where I saw it repeatedly used is along the lines of _"I'm feeling quite better now,"_ but, of course, _better_ in that context is state of being, not a comparative. So even some of those "quite better" instances would be false hits.